# Отправка файла через телеграм бота по вызову функции

Tags: python, aiogram

Столкнулся с проблемой, , нужно по вызову функции кидать файл через телеграм бота определенному пользователю через chat_id. Как это можно реализовать и что лучше использовать?

```
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor 
from aiogram import types


chat_id = 'chat_id'


TOKEN = "token"

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler()
def bot_message(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "123")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

что то типа этого кода, нужно что бы при запуске программы бот присылал 123 пользователю по chat_id

Comment: так вам нужно отправлять `123` или файл?

Comment: нужен файл, 123 я поставил как пример что бы стало понятнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="send")
async def new_message(message: types.Message):
  with open('Тут твой файл', 'rb') as f:
    await bot.send_document(chat_id=chat_id, document=f)
```

По команде `/send` бот отправит твой файл в нужный чат, заданный в `chat_id`